# Will chmod 700 my server top directory make me any safer?

Tags: linux, permissions

I am deploying my Django/Python server on a `Ubuntu 17.04` machine that includes also `Postgres`, `Redis`, `Nginx`, `uwsgi` and `Exim4`. Postgres and Redis are only listening through unix sockets and not on TCP port. I rsynced my server using `-avP` options to my cloud `home` directory and I have set up a hopefully secure `iptables` configuration.

I know that the above info may not be very related to the question but I wanted to give some details about my environment. Will changing the permissions of my server root to `700` make me any safer? What will happen when I sync later after changing some `.py` file in my dev machine or add some new file? will it be changed automatically to `700`or do I have to `chmod` it again after every `rsync` operation?

Comment: Are you readlly talking about about `chmod 700 /`?

Comment: I am talking about doing `chmod 700 /home/me/server`

Comment: I guess you misunderstodd the title. I changed it!

Comment: You probably shouldn't be running services out of a home directory. For testing it's fine but if you're talking production it belongs in a standard directory.

Comment: I don't understand what a `standard directory` means, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

To access any file on Unix-like systems, you need *search* permission to all the directory components that lead to them.

For instance, to be able to open `/a/b/c` for reading, you need search permission (the `x` bit in `ls -l` output) to `/`, `/a` and `/a/b` and `read` (the `r` bit) to `/a/b/c`.

So, if you restrict the search permissions of `/`, you're actually restricting access to every file.

With `/` typically having a owner id of 0, having 700 permissions means no user but root will have access to any file. Anyway `root` has access to any file, regardless of permissions.

What that means is that for that system to be able to do anything (as most things involve opening one file or the other), everything would have to run as `root`, that is, the user that can do anything.

So in effect, you'd be throwing away the security benefits that user access control brings. Not so much by changing the permissions of `/` to 0700 but by changing your system so everything runs as root for it to be usable with a `/` with 0700 permissions.

Comment: Thank you but I meant `chmod 700 /home/me/my_server_top_directory` NOT `chmod 700 /`

Answer (score 0):

You mean `chmod 700 --recursive /`? This only will cause problems. Since you said the server is not shared, the folder permissions are not that important. The application security is important. Check `SELinux`, although is advanced stuff.

`rsync` has switches to handle permissions. You can `--chmod=CHMOD           affect file and/or directory permissions` during sync to apply proper permission to the destination.

Comment: Thank you! I meant `chmod 700 --recursive /home/me/server` NOT chmoding the root directory of the entire system. Was that your intention?

Comment: `/home/me/server` should have permission only to the process that uses it, probably apache, nginx, etc, not exactly the root user. Anyway, always test.